# Alphabetical Paging forASP.NET AJAX Combobox asp.net c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, combobox, paging

I have a form in which I will have asp.net AJAX ComboBox  which will load 5000+ names & ID { Name --> Text , ID --> Value}.

Question is, it is taking long time to load the data. Is there any way like Alphabetical Paging in Association to ComboBox or list so that when user Selects an Alphabet she will get the list loaded with records having that Alphabet as the first  ( name like 'alphabet%') in the record.

As there is huge data, for Auto Complete I am using AJAX COMBOBOX but is there any way to achieve Alphabetical Paging ?

Is this achievable ?

Answer (score 0):

This has paging but no Auto Complete http://dotnetspeaks.com/DisplayArticle.aspx?ID=98